# originating attribute value in dialog box maximo

Tags: java, dialog, maximo

I am try to get originating attribute value in Maximo dialog box. I am not sure how to get. We have custom application and custom object. This application will display multiple asset records and I have requirement to open create move/modify Asset from that dialog. I am try to find attribute value in dialog box. Any help would be appreciated.

[customapplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfT1m.jpg)

Comment: I got dataattribute name using following statement. 
this.sourceControl = this.clientSession.getCurrentEvent().getSourceControlInstance();
this.srcDataAttribute = this.sourceControl.getProperty("dataattribute");

Comment: I am not sure how to get attribute value of that particular records.